# XSD element contains only simpleType

Tags: xml, xsd

How to construct the XSD so that

```
<foo>
    <bar>abc</bar>
    <foobar>def</foobar>
</foo>
```

is valid but

```
<foo>
    <bar>
        <foobar>abc</foobar>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

is not. In other words, how to define element foo in XSD so that it can only contain simple type elments regardless of their names? The child element name of foo is undefined (it can be any name).

Comment: Can you use version 1.1 of the schema language?

Comment: Please only apply relevant tags. Neither [tag:xslt] nor [tag:xquery] are for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using version 1.1 of the schema language I think that

```
<xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert id="simpleType-children" test="not(*/*)"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

asserts that there are no grandchildren.